# React Native TextInput max number of word

Tags: javascript, react-native

How do you set a limit for the a maximum number of words in a TextInput component in React Native ?

Comment: Try checking the value as it is entered, and splitting the spaces and counting the words.
For limiting, I thought of disabling the input but I think its not the case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it this way

```
 const [input, setInput] = React.useState('');
  const WORDS_LIMIT = 5;

  const handleChangeText = (val) => {
    const words = val.split(' ');
    if (words.length < WORDS_LIMIT) {
      setInput(val);
    }
  };
```

[snack](https://snack.expo.io/@yoel301/carefree-donuts)

Answer (score 2):

react native textInput has own property `maxLength`
[text input documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#maxlength)

```
<TextInput
 maxLength={5}
/>
```

Comment: This does not count the number of words, but the number of characters.